# Servlet application: Http session timeout

Tags: java, servlets

Hi just want to confirm when a session is expired in a webapp based on servlet. 
The following session id will be available until the session is garbage collected, is that correct? 
**httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId()**

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the session got expired, then at that point the session will be garbage collected and

> httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId() will return new value when that method is called.

please check below url

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.1/api/javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestedSessionId%28%29

Answer (score 0):

When a session is expired getRequestedSessionId() return id new session which will be created when you call this method

To check if session is timed-out (in invalid state) check [isRequestedSessionIdValid](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isRequestedSessionIdValid%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

From [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.1/api/javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestedSessionId%28%29)

> - getRequestedSessionId
>
>   public abstract String
>     getRequestedSessionId()
>
>   Gets the session id specified with this request. This may differ from the
>     actual session id. For example, if the
>     request specified an id for an invalid
>     session, then this will get a new
>     session with a new id.
>
>   Returns:
>         the session id specified by this request, or null if the request
>     did not specify a session id